# a WinForm application which is not influenced by ClearType global settings

Tags: .net, winforms, fonts, gdi+, cleartype

I have a main Form (WinForm) which should render its content without ClearType. More precisely, a RichTextBox within that form should render its text without ClearType. When ClearType is turned on at the end-user system, how can I prevent it from affecting my application?

I havn't found how to achieve this with System.Drawing, nor I know of a P/Invoke solution.

Comment: How is it affecting your application?

Comment: leppia: It affect the text within the RichTextBox user input area

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to set it but you can check from

```
  int x = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.FontSmoothingType; 
//x=1 when SmoothingType is Standard
//x=2 when SmoothingType is ClearType
```